# Limit access to advanced user (self)

Tags: software-rec, hardware-rec, parental-controls

i've got a  personal problem:
i am a computer games addict and i need to limit my access to games (forbid all games, actually).
*I know i should solve this problem from the other end e.g. find interesting hobbies, etc. But i tried it several times and failed.*
Basically, i need a way to make it impossible to play games on pc, yet being able to use it for other purposes, **which include** programming using popular languages and web surfing. Thing is, i am kind of advanced user, so i can see no software way (that i can not bypass having physical access to pc) to do this. **Added:** popular mainstream games are cross-platform or Wineable nowadays :-/
Only thing that comes to my mind: change pc video card to something older, like 64 MB, so i wont be able to play any *new* games.
So i'm asking you, guys, for help :-)

Comment: Sell your PC and buy a Mac

Comment: The Mac still has access to many games.

Comment: At times I've wanted a way for my computer to turn itself off when it gets late so I don't stay up too late playing games. Reminds me of the "droud" timer Louis Wu created in Ringworld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is not operating system on the planet that does not have access to some kind of game, you could always install an alternative to Windows/Mac/Linux that will never allow you to play "mainstream" games. You can try [Haiku](http://www.haiku-os.org/) or [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/), both operating systems offer web browsing, application development, word processing, etc without access to what ost people would consider gaming. Not only will they not run any mainstream, boxed games, but flash support is minimal or non existant. You would not even be able to run Flash games.

The other option is to install something like a [MAtrox G450](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrox_G400). I used to own one before dual monitor connections became common place. I can tell you from experience, it barely played games when it first came out.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

1. Give your windows install disc(s) to a friend who won't give them back unless ABSOLUTELY necessary.
2. Download Linux Install disc(ubuntu perhaps?)
3. Burn it
4. Boot from it, wipe out Windows OS
5. Install Linux, and stick with it.
6. Remove the games directory

Answer (score 0):

can you (or do you already) use a GNU/Linux system?

If yes you are half-way to the solution (I'm a GNU/Linux user and gaming with this OS could be sometimes a little frustating); then I would suggest to install a minimum environment.

For example, do you need your machine for some kind of job? What kind of job? *answer*, then set up your machine to be able to do just that. If you require some programming environment, you could install just a minimum distro, say Archlinux/Slackware/Ubuntu server, the Xserver and the software you really need to do your work. Nothing more. If you begin installing flashplayer, you should end up playing some flash game with your browser, thus cheating...

Also, if you knows someone that you trust, you could ask him to put a superuser/administrator password and to not revail it to you, until you are free from your addiction (the decision of how many months/years/ages are necessary to achieve this are up to you, though, so be honest with yourself).

So, firstly, you need Will to do it, and the above suggestions could just help you to achieve your results; but without willpower you'll surely fall again. Keep it strong, and you will do it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows, uninstall DirectX.

Else downgrade to:

1. Windows XP Home Edition. or
2. Windows Vista Home Starter. or
3. Cheapest Windows 7 in the market. or
4. Easiest & cheapest: Install Linux (PC OS Linux, Knopix)